# ContainsKey is true, but still "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, .net

I have such condition

```
//  `xyz` is a `dictionary<string, MyCustomType>`.
if(smth){
    xyz["ord_82"] = Func() ;// That Returns  "MyCustomType" object
}
if(xyz.ContainsKey("ord_82"){
    Print("started");
    Print(xyz["ord_82"].ToString());   // <----------------  sometimes this line throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
    Print("ended");
}
```

I couldnt find out what could be the reason.. You see, that `ContainsKey` is passed, but still throws an error..

Comment: So did you look at what `xyz["ord_82"]` returns? Presumably it's returning null, which is perfectly valid...

Comment: For this kind of problem you should use `TryGetValue` - rather than `ContainsKey` and `[]`. It will be more performant. Changing to `TryGetValue` won't solve your problem though - you still need to read @GiladGreen 's solution.

Comment: @mjwills thnks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the key `"ord_82"` exists the value mapped by it can still be null. Therefore `xyz["ord_82"].ToString()` can still through `NullReferenceException`.

Use `?.` operator from C# 6.0:

```
Print(xyz["ord_82"]?.ToString());
```

Notice that this will produce `null` for `Print`'s argument so you can do:

```
Print(xyz["ord_82"]?.ToString() ?? "");
```

---

For an earlier version of C# use the `?:` operator (The `?.` is just a sugar syntax to it:

```
var value = xyz["ord_82"];
Print(value == null ? "" : value.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks! can you give me similar solution for net 3.5? `?.` doesnt work in 3.5

Comment: @T.Todua - see update please

Comment: @T.Todua: `?.` works fine with .NET 3.5 - but you need the C# 6 compiler. It's worth being very clear about the difference between *framework* features (or CLR features, indeed) and *language* features. You can very often use new language features even if you're targeting old frameworks.

Comment: @JonSkeet aah, my bad, i am newbie and didnt know these details .  Most of the answers mentiod like: `...for C# 6 and later..` and I assumed that those features were for `net 4.0` and later... Now I understand, thanks!  (p.s. So, i can even use C#7 features with net3.5, right? wow, good.)

Answer (score 0):

`xyz["ord_82"] = Func() ;// That Returns  "MyCustomType" object`

Check if `Func()` is returning null object of MyCustomType

`xyz["ord_82"].ToString()` is called on the value returned by `xyz["ord_82"]` which is null and `.ToString()` on null will throw "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception which is `NullReferenceException`

So your code either should be changed like:

```
    //  `xyz` is a `dictionary<string, MyCustomType>`.
    if(smth){
     var obj = Func(); // That Returns  "MyCustomType" object
     if(obj != null) {
      xyz["ord_82"] = obj;
     }
    }
```

or like:

```
MyCustomType val = null;
if(xyz.TryGetValue("ord_82", out val)){
     Print("started");
     Print(val.ToString());
     Print("ended");
    }
```

Corrections edited. Thanks @mjwills for the pointers

Comment: Your second code block does a hash lookup three times - when if you used `TryGetValue` you would only need one (i.e. much faster).

Comment: That's true, there are numerous ways to optimize this code.